# Virtual host not working on XAMPP, something very strange happenning

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Hi I have browsed all the resources, but still seems can't find the solution.

I have XAMPP Control Panel v 3.2.4 (compiled Jun 5th 2019) installed on my computer, it is installed in d:\xampp. I want to create a Virtual host, so that I can correctly  use various global PATH variables.

I followed instructions closely.

This is from my D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
     <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName ikeen.localhost
     DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\ikeen"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\ikeen">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all        
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

I have added following lines to the end of httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have the following line in my hosts file in windows:

```
127.0.0.1      ikeen.localhost
```

This is the structure of my site directory

[image]

In order to avoid cache I open URL in the incognito mode and from different browsers. I always get redirect to dashboard - https://ikeen.localhost/dashboard/, it opens the standard "Welcome to XAMPP for Windows 7.4.3"

I have heard that it has something to do with https, as I'm always transferred to https URL even if I try to use http. I've looked at httpd-ssl.conf, but I don't know what to do there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Finally! For everyone who is looking for the solution do the following:

My desired site is located at D:\xampp\htdocs\ikeen.

**1) Add this to your httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
     <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName ikeen.localhost
     DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs\ikeen"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs\ikeen">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all        
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

**2) Add this to the end of httpd.conf:**

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**3) Add this line to your hosts file in Windows directory**

```
127.0.0.1      ikeen.localhost
```

**4) Finally, this is the step that is missing from all the solutions. Add this to your httpd-ssl.conf, after the same section for your localhost (usually www.example.com), change example.com to your local settings for localhost, so that the whole section looks smth like this**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
#ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "D:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "D:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

#   General setup for the ikeen host
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/ikeen"
#ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerName ikeen.localhost
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "D:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "D:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Problem was solved by removing the standard virtual host entry and i wasn't redirected to the root directory.

Just remove these lines of code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "D:\xampp\htdocs"
     <Directory "D:\xampp\htdocs">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There is another problem that I found and I fixed it. Many antiviruses install special plugin to the browsers, so when you try to open localhost they will block it even with the valid certificate. KAV is mainly at fault here.

Comment: @DeadApe By removing this you render the XAMPP Dashboard inaccesible.

Answer (score 1):

If the case does not work, maybe change httpd-ssl.conf

My 3 sites worked, localhost, test1.com, test2.com

```
#
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

...
</VirtualHost>

#test1
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/test1"
ServerName test1.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

...
</VirtualHost>

#test2
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/test2"
ServerName test1.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "c:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

...
</VirtualHost>
```